# Selecting data-control-name

Tags: javascript

So I was trying to create a script which automatically adds people in linkedin

Now on inspecting the DOM, there are several sort of buttons like the one which says invite sent, message and connect.

Here is how the button for the same looks like

For the one with connect, it looks like this

```
<button aria-label="Connect with" data-control-name="srp_profile_actions" class="search-result__actions--primary button-secondary-medium m5" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6357="6357" data-is-animating-click="true">
  Connect
```

and for the one with message it looks like this

```
</button><button aria-label="Send message" class="message-anywhere-button button-secondary-medium search-result__actions--primary m5" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6352="6352">
        Message
    </button>
```

Now both of them have this difference of `data-control-name="srp_profile_actions"` i.e the connect have this one and message does not..

So how can I select button element that have `data-control-name="srp_profile_actions"`?

Comment: Were you successful in creating that script? I am trying to do something similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this to select the button once you have something to act as a unique identifier. I'm going to distinguish them by `aria-label` but you can use that `data` attribute, either, if you want:

```
document.querySelector('button[aria-label="Connect with"]'); // Connect with button
document.querySelector('button[aria-label="Send message"]'); // Send message button
```

Then to click on one, for example, you can just add `click()` as follows:

```
document.querySelector('button[aria-label="Connect with"]').click();
```

Just to directly answer your question, though, this would be the selector you need for your `data` attribute:

```
document.querySelector('button[data-control-name="srp_profile_actions"]').click();
```

Comment: i do not working for me <button aria-label="Connectez-vous avec a . b. Chargée de recrutement at AMEG GROUP Ingénierie Industrielle, Région de Grenoble, France" class="search-result__action-button search-result__actions--primary button-secondary-medium m5" data-control-name="srp_profile_actions" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-253="253">
        Se connecter
    </button>